# Unused @Binds methods with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, androidinjector

I have the following definition of the Splash screen Activity:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(
        SplashActivitySubcomponent.ComponentModule::class)
)
interface SplashActivitySubcomponent : AndroidInjector<SplashActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<SplashActivity>()

    @Module
    abstract class ComponentModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ActivityKey(SplashActivity::class)
        abstract fun bindSplashActivityInjectorFactory(builder: SplashActivitySubcomponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
    }
}
```

I do not have fragments in the Activity. What happens is that `bindSplashActivityInjectorFactory` is unused. The problem is that I can't get rid of it otherwise the app crashes at runtime.

To use

```
@Suppress("unused")
```

isn't enough because I still get a warning from the kotlin-lint.
Why do I need to define this method when it is not used? What can I do to avoid the warning?

This is the error I get:

> UnnecessaryAbstractClass - [ComponentModule] at
>   com/xxxx/splash/di/SplashActivitySubcomponent.kt:20:5
>
> OptionalAbstractKeyword - [bindSplashActivityInjectorFactory] at
>   com/xxxx/splash/di/SplashActivitySubcomponent.kt:22:9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I fixed the problem doing this:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(SplashActivitySubcomponent.ComponentModule::class))
interface SplashActivitySubcomponent : AndroidInjector<SplashActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<SplashActivity>()

    @Module
    @Suppress("UnnecessaryAbstractClass", "OptionalAbstractKeyword")
    abstract class ComponentModule {
        @Suppress("unused")
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ActivityKey(SplashActivity::class)
        abstract fun bindSplashActivityInjectorFactory(builder: SplashActivitySubcomponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
    }
}
```

So I just added:

```
@Suppress("UnnecessaryAbstractClass", "OptionalAbstractKeyword")
```